# Use existing login for another subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, security

I have a website I made with asp.net security login with membership provider. I also added a pre-built asp.net forum as a separate web application within my website but it has its own login system and sql table structure. I don't want users to have to create 2 different logins to access the forums. Is there anyway I can use the originals login for the forum? I know this is a vague question, but let me know what you need to know to answer this. Thanks. I am using Jibit ASPNETForum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation on Jibit site](http://www.jitbit.com/docs/asp-net-forum/!!!asp-net-forum-software-readme.htm#sso) states that they can integrate with asp.net forms authentication and membership providers. See 'ASP.NET Forms/Windows Authentication' section.
According to docs you can either set credentials manually in profile, or forum will try to auto-recognize it if "IntegratedMembership" flag is enabled.